# Capybara error on HTTP.get: HTTP::ConnectionError Exception: failed to connect: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rack, minitest

My app is set to use Capybara and minitest with RackTest driver. This is the main config in test_helper.rb:

```
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/minitest'

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Capybara::DSL
  include Capybara::Minitest::Assertions

  fixtures :all

  ...

  Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"
  Capybara.run_server = true
  Capybara.server_port = 3000
  Capybara.register_driver :rack_test do |app|
    Capybara::RackTest::Driver.new app,
      follow_redirects:false
  end

  ...
end
```

Now, when I perform request directly on my tests they work fine. Such as:

```
post '/api/v4/login', params: {"email": u.email, "password": u.password }
```

But in one test I'm calling a class (inside /app) that performs the following method:

```
HTTP.get(url,params).body
```

For which i appear to have no server running and get the following Error message in response:

```
HTTP::ConnectionError Exception: failed to connect: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be using `post` or `get` in tests that use Capybara (feature/system tests). They should only be used in request/raw integration tests, which don't use Capybara or the server it starts (lazily when the need is detected through a `visit` call) and are generally used for API tests.

Second, you should not be setting the port (to 3000), or app_host (generally) when having Capybara run the AUT.  Port 3000 is generally the port your development server gets run on (`rails s`) so having Capybara run on the same port in test mode would conflict. If you don't have a really specific need for Capybara to be on a specific port (firewall forwarding, etc) then just let it pick a random port.

```rb
Capybara.run_server = true
Capybara.register_driver :rack_test do |app|
  Capybara::RackTest::Driver.new app, follow_redirects:false 
end
```

That will then have Capybara start the app on `127.0.0.1:<random_port>`, if you want it specifically on `localhost` (due to special networking needs, IPv6, etc) then you can set `Capybara.server_host = 'localhost'`. Also the use of `follow_redirects: false` is questionable since your tests that use Capybara really shouldn't be checking status codes, but rather what the user sees.

Beyond all that, if you are running a request test that ends up calling app code that does a HTTP::get you'll either need to change that test to be a feature/system test (uses Capybara, starts its own server, uses `visit`, etc) or mock/stub the request.

Comment: thanks @Thomas Walpole. This is within an integration test, thou. I should be able to call the method, shouldn't I?

Comment: @ntonnelier No - you can't mix get/post calls with Capybara - it knows nothing about them or the page state return from them.  If you're using Capybara in the test you should only be using `visit`, that's part of the reason current Rails added the system tests (which derive from IntegrationTest but remove the get/post/etc methods)